# Removing white space in text after the image moves

Tags: spacing, floats

I'm writing a thesis and have about 80 figures. The text leads up to the figure with a single line space:

```
....text text text text.

\begin{figure}[h]
....
\end{figure}

More text, and so on...
```

My issue is that sometimes, maybe 3 times in total, latex decides not to stitch the text together once it has placed the figure where it sees fit.

So:

```
    This is example text this is example text this is example text this is
example text this is example text this is example text this is example text
this is example text.

    Text begins again, this is example text this is example text this is
example text this is example text this is example text this is example text
this is example text.
```

Instead of:

```
 This is example text this is example text this is example text this is
example text this is example text this is example text this is example text
this is example text.
    Text begins again, this is example text this is example text this is
example text this is example text this is example text this is example text
this is example text.
```

When I place a full page figure, it gets worse. The white space is about 4 lines-worth.

Anyway, regardless of identical code to similar figures, sometimes it will happen and sometimes not. Is there a way to force stitching of the text at either side of the figure code?

Comment: If the image belongs to the upper text, put a `%` in the line above (instead of the blank line). If it belongs to the next paragraph, do that replacement for the line below. Right now, you start a new paragraph twice. Always wrong and mostly noticeable if the image gets set somewhere else.

Comment: you are welcome. You might want to delete your question. The topic is not new at all but I have no time to find the duplicates now. If you can't find any good post on this topic and think, it will serve others in future, you might write an answer to your own question. Thank you.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi that should not happen. `\par` in vertical mode does not start a paragraph twice, it does nothing.

Comment: @Slappy is your text above and below the figure really just plain text as shown (in which case this should not happen) or is it an environment such as theorem or quota (in which case it should not happen in an ideal world, but it might happen in practice) ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, it is just plain text...no idea why it was happening. It is currently a 80k word document so I assumed it must be to do with the shuffling of floats? Either way, a '%' fixed it.

Comment: glad you got it working but there is a bug somewhere. If you could make a test case that reproduces this it would be useful for latex maintenance, even if you don't need it...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am surprised you have not seen this yet. I always get this space when doing blank lines in front and after an image. Slappy, in this case it would be nice if you extend your question to an MWE and tell us which LaTeX-command you use to compile. Thanks.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi see the MWE I posted in an answer. If you could modify that to show the effect...

Answer (score 1):

You should get no extra space when leaving a blank line around a float as shown in this example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength\baselineskip{20pt}
\setlength\parskip{30pt}
\setlength\unitlength{50pt}


aaaa1\begin{picture}(0,0)
\put(0,0){\line(1,0){1}}
\put(0,-1){\line(1,0){1}}
\put(0,-2){\line(1,0){1}}
\put(0,-3){\line(1,0){1}}
\put(0,-4){\line(1,0){1}}
\end{picture}

aaaa2

\begin{figure}[p]xxx\end{figure}

aaaa3


aaaa4


aaaa5


\end{document}
```